# variableScopes can only resolve variable names: null in JBPM7.32

Tags: jbpm

we have a script task in jbpm , and code is below.

## Script Task code:

```
java.lang.String resTmp = (java.lang.String) kcontext.getVariable("Result");
org.json.JSONArray objects = new org.json.JSONArray(resTmp);
org.json.JSONArray finalArray = new org.json.JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
  org.json.JSONObject  jsonObject = objects.getJSONObject(i);
    if (jsonObject.getString("card_id").equals(card_id)) {
        finalArray.put(jsonObject);
    }
} 
kcontext.setVariable((java.lang.String)FResult, finalArray.toString());
```

The build is successful but we are seeing the following error while starting the workflow.

**variableScopes can only resolve variable names: null**

Comment: did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the last line to:

```
kcontext.setVariable("FResult", finalArray.toString());
```

The `setVariable()` method's first parameter is a `String`, so you have to put the name your variable between double quotes (" ")